# SetInterval happening faster than desired

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I've been playing with HTML5 and Canvas, and so I'd appreciate to have a constant framerate for what I'm doing. For that purpose, I'm trying to use javascript's setInterval, but it seems that setInterval loops FASTER than desired.

For testing purposes, I concocted a little test script, as follows:

```
var start = new Date();
var frames = 0;

setInterval(function() { 
    frames++;
    var d = new Date();
    if (d.getTime() - start.getTime() > 1000) {
        console.log(frames);
        frames = 0;
        start = d;
    }
}, 1000/60);
```

This script supposedly prints how many "frames" were counted in one second. If setInterval worked right, it would print "60" constantly on the console. However, Chrome and Firefox give me 63 frames per second, whereas Internet Explorer 9 gives me between 66 and 67 frames per second (always the worst offender).

Raising 1000 milisseconds to 20000 gives me an average of 62.5 fps on Chrome, 62.4 fps on Firefox and 66.0 on Internet Explorer.

I've read this [very enlightening article on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) about setTimeout where they mention "clamping", and I thought that could be one possible reason. However, for 60fps, the timeout would be 16.6ms, higher than any of the clamps used.

I also thought it could be a timer error, giving me one or two frames off, but the test with 20000ms returned the same average fps, so it isn't the timers either.

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? That's a very weird behavior. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay for setTimeout is an integer (milliseconds). `1000/60` is `16.67`, which gets truncated to `16`. `1000/16` is `62.5`. IE's clock runs in 15ms increments, so it probably runs the function at 15ms intervals, so `66.7` fps.

All that fits with your observed behaviour.

On top of that you have the vagaries of setTimeout and setInterval not running at exactly the requested delay, so if the system suddenly gets busy (say responding to a network request, scroll action, etc.) the frame rate will slow or become jerky trying to catch up.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this method does not produce consistent results.  You have to factor in the actual execution time of the script in question, short as it may be.

I've heard that requestAnimationFrame works better for this use.

[A snippet from the Mozilla Developer Network about it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame)

[A nice article about it](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

Comment: If [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) is correct (and he seems to be on this at least), setInterval will not wait (and if it did, the OPs results would be different). It will schedule a new call at the specified interval, even if the last one is still executing. It will not queue another though if one is waiting to be called.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this function seems rather interesting. I think my application is lightweight enough to assure that it won't reach the timer cap described in the article.